# How to get a CharField's value as a string inside the model class?

Tags: python, django

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='commenter', null=True)
    txt = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    
    summary = str(txt)[:30] + '...'
```

How can I get the `txt`'s value as a string and save it in summary? The code above returns something like this as a string: `<django.db.models.fields.CharF...`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save txt to summary unless necessary. You can use a class method or property of a class to get the summary.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='commenter', null=True)
    txt = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    
    def get_summary(self):
        return str(self.txt)[:30] + '...'

    @property
    def summary(self):
        return str(self.txt)[:30] + '...'
```